# No such label error with spring cloud config server with composite config of two git repos

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud-config

We have a spring cloud config server with a composite configuration like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          uri: "https://github.comcast.com/config-org/{application}"
          username: "mainUsername"
          password: "mainPassword"
          searchPaths: "*"
        -
          type: git
          uri: "https://github.comcast.com/config-org/shared-repo"
          username: "sharedUsername"
          password: "sharedPassword"
          searchPaths: "*"
        health:
          enabled: false
```

Here's the issue we're running into. Given that there is a repository named `xsp-reference-service`, when the cloud config client makes a request to the config server with a label for a branch that exists in the application (`xsp-reference-service`) repository, but not in the shared (`shared-repo`) repository, we get this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-04T16:18:43.886+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No such label: schrodingers_branch",
    "path": "/xsp-reference-service/dev/schrodingers_branch"
}
```

Is there a way we can either tell Spring Cloud Config Server to not worry about the missing branch in the shared repository (fail gracefully)?  If not, can we force cloud config server to use a default label (branch name) if the provided one does not exist?  I'll even take suggestions on maybe a different setup that would serve our use case better.  Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Note that for your second question, "can we force cloud config server to use a default label (branch name) if the provided one does not exist?", I submitted an enhancement request for that a few months ago: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1519

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the required rep to comment nor do I know how to tell Spring Cloud Config Server to gracefully fail.  That being said, I was able to find some information [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories)[1].

Two important points from the above documentation:

> - Any type of failure when retrieving values from an environment
>     repository results in a failure for the entire composite environment.
> - When using a composite environment, it is important that all
>     repositories contain the same labels. If you have an environment
>     similar to those in the preceding examples and you request
>     configuration data with the master label but the Subversion repository
>     does not contain a branch called master, the entire request fails.

It might be in your best interest to revisit your design with having a shared repo.  One alternative could be to use [Spring Vault](https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault)[2].  Then (taken from the same above link) you can define distinct types of repositories and no longer have this composite labeling problem.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: git, vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///path/to/git/repo
          order: 2
        vault:
          host: 127.0.0.1
          port: 8200
          order: 1
```

1: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories

2: https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault

Comment: The shared repository is kind of crucial for us. We may just solve it programmatically.  The branches in the application repository are created by a Concourse pipeline job.  We may wind up coding that job to create matching branches in the shared repository.

I'd rather not increase the complexity by adding Vault to this, especially since we are already having issues with the fact that you can't request specific versions of properties with it.

Comment: Assuming your shared repository has some kind of mechanism to avoid numerous stale branches that sounds reasonable.  
Let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: Loading: Will do.  I hope someone from Spring sees this though.  I don't think this would be such an outrageous setup, and having a graceful degrade option would really help expand the use cases for the config server.